# Javascript: calling function twice causes unwanted behavior

Tags: javascript

Function **cooldown()** is supposed to have pretty simle efect.On call, it is supposed to create division with proportions of element used as argument of function.And afterwards, created divison is supposed to reduce it's width in *time* (*time* is argument again).And what needs to be mentioned too is that while function cooldown() is running (or while division's width is being reduced until 0), element **cooldown()** is called on is not visible.

You may want to see [this fiddle which shows how it works](http://jsfiddle.net/0ot4ry3h/3/).

My problem comes, when we call this function twice on two different elements at the same time.[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0svkj99x/7/).When we click first red rectangle and right then black one, both cooldowns start.But when the first is finished, instead of appearing red rectangle, black rectangle appears.And red stays invisible.Any ideas?

*Notice essential function **erase()** responsible for hiding element:*

```
function erase(id,delay)
{

 document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = 0;

 setTimeout(function exec()
 {

  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
 },delay);
}
```

*And function **cooldown()** :*

```
   function cooldown(id,time)
   {
    el = document.getElementById(id);
    parent = document.getElementById(id).parentNode;

    erase(el.id,500);

     cdshadow = document.createElement("div"); 

     cdshadow.className = "movefalse";
     cdshadow.style.backgroundColor = "black";
     cdshadow.style.transition = "width "+time/1000+"s";
     cdshadow.style.opacity = 0.7;
     cdshadow.style.transitionTimingFunction = "linear";
     cdshadow.style.borderRadius = 5 +"px";
     cdshadow.style.position = "absolute";
     cdshadow.style.width = el.offsetWidth +"px";
     cdshadow.style.height = el.offsetHeight +"px";
     cdshadow.style.left = el.offsetLeft +"px";
     cdshadow.style.top = el.offsetTop +"px";

     parent.appendChild(cdshadow);

    setTimeout(function shorten(){cdshadow.style.width = 0;},1);

    setTimeout(function show_back()
    {
     el.style.visibility = "visible";
     el.style.opacity = 1;

    },time);

  return time;
 }
```

Comment: "doctor it hurts when I raise my arm" "then don't raise your arm."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your variable are global. Define the variables like bellow.

So it getting mixed for both `divs.` Make them local to that function using `var.`

```
var el = document.getElementById(id);
var parent = document.getElementById(id).parentNode;

var cdshadow = document.createElement("div");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0svkj99x/8/)